# Rounding in PHP to achieve 100%

Tags: php

I need to total the number of clicks over 10 links on my page and then figure out the percentage of people that clicked each. This is easy division, but how do I make sure that I get a round 100% at the end.

I want to use the below code, but am worried that a situation could arise where the percentages do not tally to 100% as this function simply removes the numbers after the period.

```
function percent($num_amount, $num_total) {
$count1 = $num_amount / $num_total;
$count2 = $count1 * 100;
$count = number_format($count2, 0);
echo $count;
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: how critical is it that you sum up to exactly 100%? You're dealing with floating point numbers, so inaccuracy is inherent, and usually people just put disclaimers onto reports saying "may not total to XXX due to rounding".

Comment: You could try `round` instead of `number_format` to see if that improves it but it will never get 100% accurate for all cases.

Comment: It is crucial for my purposes that I can total to 100 as often as possible if not every time

Comment: But what do you expect the result to be if you have 9 times 10.1 and 1 time 9.1? There simply is no perfect solution.

Comment: sorry can you explain your numbers? At what point in the function would that be possible?

Comment: In general, if you have 10 links you measure, a result could look like that and the rounded numbers don't add up.

Comment: From with amount of percentage on you want to "round up" ? From 95 % ? 99.0 ? 99.1 ? 99.99 ?

Comment: New answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12609122/212940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is this.

Total the number of clicks across the board, then divide each number by the total.
For example:

```
1134
5391
2374
2887
```

In this case, four buttons, with a total of 11786 clicks, so:

```
1134 / 11786 = 0.09621....
5391 / 11786 = 0.45740....
2374 / 11786 = 0.20142....
2887 / 11786 = 0.24495....
```

Then for each division, round the result to 'two decimal points', so the first result:

```
0.09621.... becomes 0.10
```

because the 3rd point is 5 or above, it would remain at 0.09 if the 3rd point was below 5.

Once you have all of the results rounded,  multiply each by 100 then add them up.
The ending result will always be 100.

Should warn you however that depending on how you use each individual percentage, when you round them, any result less that 0.05 will become 0%, unless you keep the value before you round it so you can declare it as a percentage less than 1.

Comment: That's not necessarily correct.  Take the values 49,66,5,67,77,34 (generated randomly in my testing).  These sum to 298, and result in the following raw percentages: 0.16442953020134, 0.22147651006711, 0.016778523489933, 0.2248322147651, 0.25838926174497, 0.11409395973154. 

When rounded to precision 2, the sum is 0.99 (0.16, 0.22, 0.02, 0.22, 0.26, 0.11).  This method is not reliable if the goal is a 100% sum.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calculating one percentage in your function you could pass all your results as an array and process it as a whole. After calculating all the percentages and rounding them make a check to see if they total 100. If not, then adjust the largest value to force them all to total 100. Adjusting the largest value will make sure your results are skewed as little as possible.

The array in my example would total 100.02 before making the adjustment.

```
function percent(array $numbers)
{
    $result = array();
    $total = array_sum($numbers);

    foreach($numbers as $key => $number){
        $result[$key] = round(($number/$total) * 100, 2);
    }

    $sum = array_sum($result);//This is 100.02 with my example array.

    if(100 !== $sum){
        $maxKeys = array_keys($result, max($result));
        $result[$maxKeys[0]] = 100 - ($sum - max($result));
    }
    return $result;
}


$numbers = array(10.2, 22.36, 50.10, 27.9, 95.67, 3.71, 9.733, 4.6, 33.33, 33.33);
$percentages = percent($numbers);
var_dump($percentages);
var_dump(array_sum($percentages));
```

Output:-

```
array (size=10)
  0 => float 3.51
  1 => float 7.69
  2 => float 17.22
  3 => float 9.59
  4 => float 32.86
  5 => float 1.28
  6 => float 3.35
  7 => float 1.58
  8 => float 11.46
  9 => float 11.46
float 100
```

This will also work with an associative array as the function parameter. The keys will be preserved.

These figures could now be presented in a table, graph or chart and will always give you a total of 100%;

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)  or [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) .

Since these are floating point numbers, there is room for error. Be careful how you round, and be sure that you don't independently calculate the last remaining percentages. Simply subtract the total of what you have from 1 or 100.

Make sure you dont calculate separate sides of the equation, sum one side, then subtract the other from 1 or 100 or however you are handling your percentages.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this quite a bit and have a hack for it.

```
$percentages = array(
    '1'         => 87.5,
    '2'         => 12.5,
    '3'         => 0,
    '4'         => 0,
    '5'         => 0
);
```

If you round those percentages for output, you will end up with 88% and 13% (101%)

```
round($percentages['1']);
round($percentages['2']);

// 88
// 13
```

So here is the code I use to fix it.

```
$checkTotal     = array_sum($percentages);
$max            = max(array_keys($percentages));

if ($checkTotal > 100) {
    $percentages[$max] = $percentages[$max] - 1;
}
if ($checkTotal < 100) {
    $percentages[$max] = $percentages[$max] + 1;
}
```

If it is 100, do nothing.

If it is less than 100, add 1 to equal 100

If it is over 100, subtract 1 to equal 100